# How to limit the selection in a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

How would I go about limiting the rows/columns selected in a QTableWidget? I need to force the user to use a contiguous selection (already done) to select exactly two columns and any amount of rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably have to do one of 2 things:

1. You would have to subclass `QItemSelectionModel` and implement functions for adding and deleting selected `QModelIndex`es so that you only add items from 2 rows to it.
2. You can do this by having a custom implementation for catching signals that `QItemSelectionModel` emits such as:

   `connect(tableWidget->selectionModel(),
           SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection &, QItemSelection &)),
           selectionHandler,
           SLOT(updateSelection(QItemSelection &, QItemSelection &)));`

The `selectionHandler` is the object that checks the rows and columns of the `QModelIndex` items in the `QItemSelection` and remove all Indices that are outside the row range that you would like the user to keep and then:

```
selectionHandler->ignoreSelectionUpdateSignal();
tableWidget->selectionModel()->select(QItemSelection&);
selectionHandler->acceptSelectionUpdateSignal();
```

The `ignore` and `accept` you need to make sure that you don't get into an infinite loop processing `selectionChanged` signal.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I think I'll just go with a simpler way which just gives a message to the user if they select too much, but that does answer my question.