# QTableView advanced selection

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, multipleselection

I work with a QTableView and I would like to develop an advanced selection mode. I have not managed to do it with [`SelectionBehavior`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum) nor with [`SelectionMode`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum).

The user shall be able to pick up some cells but only if they belong to the same column:

- **VALID BEHAVIOURS**:

[image: Select an entire column is OK]
[image: Select some cells in the same column is OK]

- **INVALID BEHAVIOUR**:

[image: Select cells in several columns is NOT OK]

The icing on the cake would be to prevent the last row (yellow one)  to be selected.

Is there any solution?

---

**EDIT - 2013/03/05**

I cannot get it work:

```
ui->table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectItems);
ui->table->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);

connect(ui->table->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentColumnChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)), ui->table->selectionModel(), SLOT(clearSelection()));
```

What's wrong with this code? I also tried `QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection` and `QAbstractItemView::ContiguousSelection`.

Comment: Related question: [How to limit the selection in a QTableWidget](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8658656/20984).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the signals from QItemSelectionModel, especially

> [signal] QItemSelectionModel::currentColumnChanged

could be used to start a new selection in case the current selection would be extended to cover two columns.

Comment: I haven't seen this signal. It could be helpful but when this signal is emitted, how to uncheck the unwanted cell?

Comment: You would probably unselect all cells that have been selected up to now, otherwise, it could be difficult to unselect a selection and start a new selection. So simply start a new selection just with the cell the user selected right now.

Comment: Yes you're right, thanks. But I've got a problem. `selectionModel()` from my `QTableView` returns null. Therefore, I cannot connect to `currentColumnChanged()`. Does it sound familiar to you?

Comment: You need to set your model first, afterwards, the selectionModel() will return a valid model. If you query selectionModel() before setModel() you will get a null instead of a valid model.